# Magento 1.9 Loop all customized product attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I have created different custom attributes for a product, as shown in screen-shot.

[image]

I want to show All attribute texts, and I have the following code to retrieve the value. It worked fine, but I don't want this "hardcoded" code. How can I loop all the attributes and get it's value without writing the lable manually?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->getSku($_item));
$productOption = $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('farve_materiale')
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('stelfarve_flet')
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('flet_materiale') 
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('stelfarve_bordplade') 
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('stelfarve') 
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('plastfod')   
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('materiale')
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('flet')
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('formelt_vaegt')
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('lounge_hynde')
. $product->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore())->getAttributeText('stelfarve_saede');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below Code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$this->getSku($_item));
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

        if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
            $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
        } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
            $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
        } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
            $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
        }

        if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
            $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                'value' => $value,
                'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
            );
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code is genius. It almost got me what I need. but this code only return the value from the label "size" in  product attributes. I wonder where all other attributes are.

Comment: It will return all the attribute which are visible at frontend  @Zhenyu

Comment: just remove **if condition** @Zhenyu Find updated code

Comment: I tried that, but that returned me everything, including description. It is possible to only show the attributes from a certain **attributes set**?

Comment: just set visible on front end for the attributes you want to show and include that if condtion @Zhenyu

Comment: I accepted it as the awswer as code if really helpful. But i can't really make all attributes to show on front-end as they don't suppose to. I will be great if I could only show the attributes from a certain attribute set. this will be exactly what i need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55898/discussion-between-zhenyu-and-gopal-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get all attribute code of dropdown and user defined filter :

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
->addFieldToFilter('frontend_input','select')
->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined','1')
->getItems();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute){
    echo $attribute->getAttributecode();
    echo '<br>';
}
```

You can add or remove filters according to your need and it will give you all attribute code.